# Python extend with an empty list bug?

Tags: python, list, extend

Why does python 2.5.2 have the following behavior

```
>>>[2].extend([]) == [2]
False

>>> [2].extend([]) == None
True

$ python --version
Python 2.5.2
```

I assume I'm not understanding something here, but intuitively I'd think that [2].extend([]) should yield [2]

Comment: Who needs intuition when there is the interpreter? Just `print [2].extend([])`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Extend is a method of list, which modifies it but doesn't return `self` (returning `None` instead). If you need the modified value as the expression value, use `+`, as in `[2]+[]`.

Answer (score 15):

Exactly.

```
>>> x = [2]
>>> x.extend([]) # Nothing is printed because the return value is None
>>> x == [2]
True
>>> x
[2]
```

They do this on purpose so that you will remember that the extend function is actually modifying the list in-place. Same with sort(). It always returns None.